# Have no access to an array after a function has been called

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, function-pointers, pass-by-reference

I am trying to change the value of ydot[] in func() so that I can use it in my ode() function. However, it seems like I do not have access to ydot[] anymore after I called func(). I am passing func() into ode() as a function pointer called dydt. Here are my two functions:

```
    void func(double t, double y[], double ydot[])
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 18; i++){
            ydot[i] = y[i]+1;
        }
    }

    typedef void (*dydt_func)(double t, double y[ ], double ydot[ ]);

    void ode(double y0[ ], double yend[ ], int len, double t0,
             double t1, dydt_func dydt)
    {
        double ydot[len];

        dydt = &func;

        //This prints out all the value of ydot[] just fine
        for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++){
            cout << ydot[i] << ",";
        }

        dydt(t1, y0, ydot);

        //This SHOULD print all the revised value of ydot[]
        //But I get an error instead:
        //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

        for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++){
            cout << ydot[i] << ",";
        }
    };
```

I have access to ydot[] just fine before I called dydt(). Is there something wrong with the way I use function pointer? Or should I pass a pointer of ydot[] or something to func() instead? Thank you guys for helping!

Comment: Since C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) your code is technically invalid.

Comment: As for your problem, please learn how to use your debugger to catch the crash in action, and locate when and where in your code it happens.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It says EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I get to the second for loop trying to print out ydot[i]. But how can I print it out successfully before I called dydt()?

Comment: By the way, will the actual sizes of the arrays you have be *at least* `18` elements? Will no one be smaller? How do you call the `ode` function? With what arguments? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us?

Comment: What value does `len` have when you call `ode`?  If it is less than 18 you've entered the realm of Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I should've initialized the array with size of `len`, but I am not sure if I can have an array with variable-length...

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I can print out the value of `ydot[]` inside `dydt()` as well. But the address of `ydot[]` became `0x0` as soon as `dydt()` is returned in `ode()`

Comment: @cxc As it was mentioned in the formerly marked [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope), you cannot access any variables or memory addresses that were stack allocated inside a particular functions scope.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Would it work if I allocate the memory inside `ode()` before it goes into the `dydt()` function? Would I still have access after I called `dydt()`?

Comment: Why are you assigning to `dydt` inside the `ode()` function? It's supposed to be a function parameter that the caller passes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ All I want is to change the value of `ydot[]` inside `dydt()`. Is there anyway I can achieve that?

Comment: Calling `func()` can't have any effect on the allocation of the `ydot` array. the only possible problem is accessing outside the array bounds, if `len < 18`.

Comment: @Barmar That is what I think! But I could not even print out `ydot[0]` after calling `func()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ doesn't have variable-length arrays like C does, so you need to use `new` to allocate the array with a variable size, or use a `std::vector` instead of an array.

You need to pass the size of the array to `func`, so that it can limit the number of elements it updates to that size. Your code will have undefined behavior if the array length is less than 18.

```
void func(double t, double y[], double ydot[], int len)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        ydot[i] = y[i]+1;
    }
}

typedef void (*dydt_func)(double t, double y[ ], double ydot[ ], int len);

void ode(double y0[ ], double yend[ ], int len, double t0,
         double t1, dydt_func dydt)
{
    double *ydot = new double[len];

    dydt = &func;

    //This prints out all the value of ydot[] just fine
    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++){
        cout << ydot[i] << ",";
    }

    dydt(t1, y0, ydot, len);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        cout << ydot[i] << ",";
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think the problem is that I did not allocate memory for `ydot` in `ode()`. Thank you all for helping!

Comment: @cxc If your compiler allows the VLA extension, you allocated it with `double ydot[len];`